# Is there any way to mix and display 2 subtitles (2 different languages) line by line?

Tags: video, subtitles, mixing

I need to read 2 subtitles with 2 different languages. I'd like to have them displayed line by line like this clip : http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H7Tg6dU_MYo 
I need one line English and one line Chinese then one line English and one line Chinese ,not one group of English lines then one group of Chinese lines.

For example :

*Sub 1 :*

**This is 

Subtitle 1**

*Sub 2 :*

And this is 
Subtitle 2

*After mix :* 

**This is** 

And this is 
**Subtitle 1** 

Subtitle 2

Hope you can understand.
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just mix the lines of the two subtitle files in one, while respecting the time of initial appearance.

Comment: Do you know any software can do that ?

Comment: It is first important to know the file format you have. Your subtitles files are .srt?

Comment: Sorry for the response delay! I don't think there's an existing software for that! You just have to open both file (in notepad) and merge manually! Just respect the timing ascending order and all will be ok!

Answer (score 2):

I realize that this question is old but it may help some people.
Disclaimer: I'm a founder of the company below!

At [fleex](http://fleex.tv), we released a video player focused on language learning.
We don't display two subtitles at the same time like you said - too difficult for the brain to read two subtitles in different languages - but we "mix" them. That is, we alternate the display of English and Chinese (for you) subtitles.

When you pause the video though, both subtitles are displayed (see picture [here](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B43ThezG5uWabmtxbjdIVEZWOVU/edit?usp=sharing))

And it's not just Chinese, we have 30 languages so pick yours!

Hope this can help someone.

Comment: I have been looking for this for a long time, thanks !